Correlations between "Names of God", "God's attributes", and the 3 common ways of knowing God ("univocal, analogical, equivocal")
When reading philosophical theology literature, I often come across 3 sets of terminologies to how a human being comes to (metaphysically) know God or to understand (conceptually) who God is:

Biblical: Names of God such as

El Shaddai, YHWH Elohim Sabaoth*, El Elyon, Haqqadosh, I am, Adonay, etc. (in the Old Testament) and

Kyrios, Abba, Emmanuel, the Alpha and Omega, etc (in the New Testament)


which is directly practical to a Christian's daily life, being referenced in

the Lord's Prayer ("Hallowed be Thy Name")
the 3rd commandment ("Do not take the name of the Lord in vain")
the liturgy ("Blessed is He who comes in the name of the Lord")
etc.


Theological: God's attributes such as the 3 omnis, Loving, Just, Good, Faithful, Holy, etc. commonly divided into many schemes such as communicable vs. incommunicable attributes, entitative vs. personal attributes, or a simple enumeration.

Philosophical: Univocally vs. analogically vs. equivocally which strong ties to the nature of language (for an introduction, see this article), where the 3 most common analogies I see are:

Analogy of faith way to interpret the Bible (see Biblical Theology and the Analogy of Faith)
Analogy of being or Analogia entis
Psychological analogy of the Trinity (see excellent article here)



My question: for theologians who want to use all 3 when describing their theologies, how do they correlate the 3 sets?

Did you mean to leave out 'spiritual' ? (By this, I mean the knowledge of God through the Person of the Holy Spirit and in faith.)
